# How to destroy query string after redirecting from one page to another page on page load event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, postback, postbackurl

I am having 2 pages name as :

- Abc.aspx
- pqr.aspx

Now on page load of **Abc.aspx** i am doing this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Alert"]))
                {
                    if (Request.QueryString["Alert"] == "y")
                    {
                      //Here on redirection from Pqr.aspx i will display Javascript alert that your "Your data save"
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                        //Dont do anything
                 }
            }

        }
```

Now from **pqr.aspx** page i am redirecting to **Abc.aspx** and passing query string on button click:

```
     protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        //saving my data to database.
        Response.Redirect("~/Abc.aspx?Alert=yes");
     }
```

But what is happening is if anybody enters url like this in browser then still this alert is coming:

```
http://localhost:19078/Abc.aspx?Alert=yes
```

Then still this javascript alert box comes.

**What i want is after redirecting from my Pqr.aspx page only this alert should come**.

How to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Asp.net** there is an object named `Request.UrlReferrer`.With this property you can get the previous page from which you come to the current page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Alert"]))
           {
               if (Request.QueryString["Alert"] == "y" && Request.UrlReferrer != null && Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath == "/pqr.aspx") // if the root is same
               {
                   //Here on redirection from Pqr.aspx i will display Javascript alert that your "Your data save"
               }
               else
               {
                        //Dont do anything
               }
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: In this Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() == "your page"."Your page" means just the name of page or should i include path in that??

Comment: @Learning it give you many methods to determine the previos page.Just try to debug that object.I have edited my asnwer see the one of many methods to determine the previos page

Comment: Got it.Thanks.I was looking for this only

Comment: i am doing this: if (Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()!=null) and now when i enter url in new tab then i get this error: if (Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()!=null).So how to handle null error?

Comment: @Learning first if (Request.UrlReferrer != null) check, then your page